# How to create migration runner shell script for apply migration for ASP.NET Web API project

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

I have a project demo.Api it is an ASP.NET Web API project. It has some migration file also. I can generate or update migration from package manager console. I want to create a shell script file for generate or update. How can I do this?

```
# Navigate to the API project directory
cd ../src/Demo.Api

# Run the migrations
dotnet ef database update
```

My `demo.api` project has inside the `src` folder. And my script file has outside the `src` folder, like (`docs/script.sh`)